# What is the difference between String? and String! in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to know the difference between String? and String! in Kotlin.
I search on kotlinlang.org but did not find any information.

Comment: ? represents nullable type and ! represents platform type . Just search for `Platform Types in kotlin` u will get the idea .

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin's type system differentiates between [nullable and non-nullable types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html). In that context, `String?` is a nullable type while `String` would be the corresponding non-nullable type.

When working with Java libraries, the compiler is not always able to identify whether a type is nullable or not, since Java does not have that differentiation. Such types will then show up as ["platform type"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) `String!`, meaning (basically): "I have no idea if this can be `null` but I'll treat it as non-nullable for now".

If you have control over the corresponding Java library, Kotlin [supports various annotations](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/compiler.common.jvm/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/load/java/JvmAnnotationNames.kt) to help distinguish between types, otherwise it is up to you as developer to explicitly assign either a nullable or a non-nullable type e.g. upon variable declaration to avoid running into `NullPointerException`s at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer with some sample code.

#### 1. String?

This means this string is nullable.

- Example 1: Use it in the type definition.

```
fun testStringTypes() {
    // When initializing stringA, we can set null as the value
    var stringA: String? = null
    // And we can also set it to a meaningful string
    stringA = "Hello"
    // Then we can still set it back to null
    stringA = null
}
```

- Example 2: a variance of String?

```
fun testStringTypes() {
    var stringA: String? = null
    stringA = "Hello"
    stringA = null
    val lenOfStringA = stringA?.length ?: 0
}
```

So here is a brief description about what this `val lenOfStringA = stringA?.length ?: 0` means:

- Because stringA is defined as nullable;
- `stringA?.length` means, access to the `length` property only if stringA is not null;
- Because if, when stringA is null and if the code still tries to access to `length` (like in Java), the program will throw a NullPointerException. `stringA?` a question mark here, is to avoid this, which is called [SafeCalls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

#### 2. String!

This is [platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types).

Copy from the link above:

> As mentioned above, platform types can't be mentioned explicitly in the program, so there's no syntax for them in the language. Nevertheless, the compiler and IDE need to display them sometimes (for example, in error messages or parameter info), so there is a mnemonic notation for them:

I think (correct me if I was wrong), this makes sense when working with Java, because `String` in Java can be null, in other words, when accessing it from Kotlin, we don't know it is null or not. So `String!` is kind of a reminder to developer: Hey! Attention, this variable could be null.

- Example 3, work with Java method from Kotlin:

```
// In Java:
public class PlatformTypeTest {
    public String returnSomeStringCouldBeNull() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And let's call this method in Kotlin.

```
fun testStringTypes() {
    val someStringFromJava = PlatformTypeTest().returnSomeStringCouldBeNull()
}
```

[image]

```
fun testStringTypes() {
    val someStringFromJava = PlatformTypeTest().returnSomeStringCouldBeNull()
    someStringFromJav
}
```

[image]

As we can see from above two screenshots, IDE is reminding us this String from Java can be null.

And for String!, we can access it in different ways:

```
fun main() {
    val someStringFromJava = PlatformTypeTest().returnSomeStringCouldBeNull()
    var lenOfString = someStringFromJava?.length ?: 0
//    lenOfString = someStringFromJava.length // NullPointerException
//    lenOfString = someStringFromJava!!.length // NullPointerException
    println(lenOfString)
}
```

With code snippet above, it works fine with `var lenOfString = someStringFromJava?.length ?: 0`, but the other two ways will cause NPE, as explained at above.

Answer (score 0):

**String?** is a [nullable type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

**String!** is a platform type [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types).

From Kotlin website:

**Nullable Types Example:**

```
val nullable: String? = item // allowed, always works
val notNull: String = item // allowed, may fail at runtime
```

**Platform Types Example:**

```
- T! means "T or T?",
- (Mutable)Collection<T>! means "Java collection of T may be mutable or not, may be nullable or not",
- Array<(out) T>! means "Java array of T (or a subtype of T), nullable or not"
```